# How to add JS programmatically in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I need to add a JS file conditionally and programmatically inside a block file. I tried with these codes:

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule/settings/enable')) {
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path-to-file/file1.js');
} else {
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path-to-file/file2.js');
}
```

However, regardless of what the setting is, none of this file is loaded. I even tried to eliminate the condition and explicitly load one file only, but it still doesn't work. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Does the conditional statement work for a simple echo/print?

Comment: Thanks Alan for your reply. Yes, the conditional does provide either 0 or 1 if I echo it out. However, I tried to eliminate the whole lines except one line:

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path-to-file/file1.js');

But it still doesn't work. The path is after js root directory.

Comment: Which block's template file are you calling this from?

Comment: Thanks Alan. It's solved already by comment from benmarks below.

Comment: To answer Alan's question, I'm calling this from the .php block file (the one with capital letter), not the .phtml block file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue here is likely one of processing order. My guess is that your PHP code is being evaluated after the head block has been rendered. While your code is successfully updating the head block class instance, it's happening after output has been generated from that instance.

The better solution will be to add the `addJs()` calls in layout XML so that they will be processed prior to rendering. It would be nice if there were an `ifnotconfig` attribute, but for now you can use a helper.

Create a helper class with a method which returns the script path based on the config settings, then use this as the return argument.

```
<?php 
class My_Module_Helper_Class extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getJsBasedOnConfig()
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mymodule/settings/enable')) {
            return 'path-to-file/file1.js';
        }
        else {
            return 'path-to-file/file2.js';
        }
    }
}
```

Then in layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <file helper="classgroup/class/getJsBasedOnConfig" />
                <!-- i.e. Mage::helper('module/helper')->getJsBasedOnConfig() -->
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Excellent! You're rock! It works, except there is a typo error in your code on "if" line. There is unneeded closed bracket prior to curl bracket.

Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: The dangers of (1) not testing and (2) coding while jet-lagged. Corrected :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path');
```

Its the right code, search if your path is right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the path is right. It's relative to the root js folder. I even tried to copy my js file to that root js folder (no sub folder) and access it directly like this addJs('file1.js');

Comment: Try put the code : <?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>jsFile.js" and see what code he write. The xml addjs is same.

Comment: What if you want to add an absolute path example http://somedomain.com/js/some.js

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but in case somebody is looking for this, I would suggest to use this in your local.xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference  name="head">
            <action ifconfig="path/to/config" method="addJs">
                <script>pathto/file.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default> 
</layout>
```

Of course this is for JS files located in /js/ folder. Use the appropriate method if you want to add skin_js or skin_css.

PS. Tested on CE 1.9